# Socket server and logic server separation

Tags: sockets, architecture, client-server, server

I think this is a pretty straight forward question, but would like to hear any pros/cons.

Say we have a simple standard client/server application.

For the server is it better to have a separate process that listens for connections and messages from clients and sends the data via local sockets or stdin to another process that runs the actual application logic server.

The other option would be to have both "activities" be done in a single process, with queueing incoming messages and executing them in the right order there shouldn't be a halting issue.

I am wondering if the extra resource to separete the two "activities" is actually worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I believe you are asking about whether you need to build [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) for your project or not.
SOA solution has a lot of advantages: autonomy of processes, loose coupling, potential for scalability etc.
The main disadvantage is a complexity, because you need to invest a lot in proper building such a solution.
If you are not talking about SOA, but just about some sort of inter-process communication, then it may share few pros and cons
with SOA solution, not having such a powerful background though.
Is it worth to separate another process, or just use a single one? It depends on actual requirements. I recommend you to read about SOA just
to get an idea about possible scenarios & solutions.